# CAML Query parameter equals string

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, caml

I have the following CAML Query. What I need in it is another clause that tests for the string "0 - 9" is equal to {ToyotapediaCharacterSelector} and if not go into the existing .

Can anyone help please?

```
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <And>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='MyCategories' />
            <Value Type='Text'>{MyCategories}</Value>
          </Eq>
          <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <Value Type='Text'>{MyCharacterSelector}</Value>
          </BeginsWith>
        </And>
      </Where>
    </Query>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a calculated column will allow you to determine if the content in your column is numeric or text. You can then use this as a filter in your view